# Finding the prior of a Bayesian model based on test data

Tags: bayesian, optimization, prior

I have a Bayesian modelling problem different somehow from standard modelling problems I have come across.

Instead of learning a posterior estimation of the parameters from some data, we are interested in *learning the prior* given two separate sets of data: input/training data (which gives likelihood) and output/test data sampled from posterior.

The simplest example:
Assume we have a coin. A person observes a number of coin flips, e.g. [0, 0, 0]. He is then asked to sample (predict) a number of next coin flips, e.g. [1, 1, 0, 1, 0]. We’re interested in estimating the prior on the coin probability *p* the person had in the beginning (for these data, it's some bias in favor of a fair coin).

- Is there a body of literature on this type of problems (of course to deal with more complicated data and models)? I'm looking for at least some key words to start with.
- Is there any software dedicated to finding priors efficiently?

I'll appreciate all comments / ideas, thanks!

Comment: If I understand you correctly you *assume* that human cognition can be described using Bayes theorem, so Bayes theorem could be used to "reverse" their thinking process..? Don't you think that this is a quite big assumption? Are you familiar with research on this topic from fields such as cognitive neuroscience and cognitive psychology (say Kahneman and Tversky for start)..? Yes you can "reverse" Bayes theorem, but I''m not sure that there is any justification in concluding that what you estimated is *the* prior someone had.

Comment: your question looks interesting, but I'm not sure I understand it. What do you mean exactly by: the person is asked to sample (predict) a number of next coin flips? Are you asking him to try to predict the next coin flips (without actually doing it) in order to see what the person's belief of the priors are?

Comment: @pascal-soucy My test case is language learning, I hope this clarifies things. So a person learns language from input data and produces a *new* language.

Comment: @tim Yes, my test case is language learning and, indeed, there is quite a lot of literature on modelling this process using Bayesian assumption: e.g. new lang | input ~ likelihood of input * prior, where prior encodes some linguistic (potentially native) constraints.